# how to replace a particular string on multiple line in vi/vim editor

Tags: regex, vim, replace, vi

***I have the following lines in a file :***

```
|other words in line| abcd_1234.xyz |other words in line|

|other words in line| abcd_2345.xyz |other words in line|

|other words in line| abcd_3456.xyz |other words in line|

|other words in line| abcd_4567.xyz |other words in line|
```

***I want to change the above lines to***

```
|other words in line| q |other words in line|

|other words in line| q |other words in line|

|other words in line| q |other words in line|

|other words in line| q |other words in line|
```

I tried `:%s/abcd*.xyz/q/g` but that does not seem to work. Please can anyone suggest how to go about this.

Comment: Your regular expression is matching strings like `abc.xyz`, `abcd.xyz`, `abcdd.xyz`, `abcddd.xyz`, etc.  You probably meant to use `.*` instead, but should most likely use `.\{-}` to match non-greedily.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
:%s/(abcd_[0-9]{4}\.xyz)/q/g
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can count on having the spaces and the `|` then you can use:

```
:%s/\|(.*)\| (abcd_.*) \|(.*)\|/\1q\3
```

PS: you can use https://regex101.com/r/DHLbIx/1 to help  you with the matching

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

`:%s/abcd.*\.xyz/q/g`

For match `.` you need to write as`\.`, remember a simple dot `.` is also a command.